# Check if wait_for_message returns only numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My below code is working fine but how to make the bot accepting the user's message only if it's numbers and say "please add only numbers" otherwise?

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(self, ctx):
    message = await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Ask something")
    reply = await self.bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
    await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}".format(reply.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and do something like

```
if reply.content.isdigit():
  await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}".format(reply.content))
else:
  await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Please add only numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `check` argument in `wait_for_message()` which can check the given message is fit to user-defined rule.

```
@commads.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(self, ctx):
    message = await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Ask something")
    def is_number(msg):
        return msg.content.isdigit()
    reply = await self.bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel, check=is_number)
    await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}".format(reply.content))
```

You can also add a handler sending "please add only numbers" in `is_number()`.